# Behat string must be an instance of Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode

Tags: php, behat

I have the following method within my `FeatureContext.php`:

```
/**
 * @When /^I send a ([A-Z]+) request to "([^"]*)" (with the data)$/
 */
public function iSendARequestToWithData($method, $uri, PyStringNode $string)
{
    $request        = $this->client->createRequest($method, $this->base_url.$uri);
    $this->response = $this->client->send($request);
}
```

When running my features, this line fails:

```
    When I send a POST request to "/items" with the data
    """
        {
            "category": 1
        }
    """
```

With the following error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 3 passed to FeatureContext::iSendARequestToWithData() must be an instance of Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode, string given in app/tests/acceptance/FeatureContext.php line 68
```

I guess it has to do with my this regular expression, especially the `(with the data)`, but I have no clue how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Behat uses [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) to match a step to the method that should be called. Regular expression **subpatterns** are used to match method arguments.

**Subpatterns**

Each subpattern from a regular expression is used as an argument to your method.

In your example:

- `([A-Z]+)` will be passed as a `$method`
- `([^"]*)` will be passed as an `$uri`
- `(with the data)` as a `$string`
- `PyStringNode` is passed as the last, in this case fourth argument.

**Non capturing subpatterns**

Use non capturing subpatterns if you don't want to capture an argument:

```
(?:non matching pattern)
```

To fix your example:

```php
/**
 * @When /^I send a ([A-Z]+) request to "([^"]*)" (?:with the data)$/
 */
public function iSendARequestToWithData($method, $uri, PyStringNode $string)
{
}
```

**Named subpatterns**

You can also use named subpatterns to explicitly say, where the matched patterns should be passed. In such case, order of arguments matched via the pattern doesn't matter, Behat will match them by name:

```php
/**
 * @When /^I send a (?P<method>[A-Z]+) request to "(?P<uri>[^"]*)" (?:with the data)$/
 */
public function iSendARequestToWithData($method, $uri, PyStringNode $string)
{
}
```

**Turnip syntax**

Behat 3 uses turnip syntax, which I recommend using if you're not familiar with regular expressions.

```php
/**
 * @When I send a :method request to :uri with the data
 */
public function iSendARequestToWithData($method, $uri, PyStringNode $string)
{
}
```

Answer (score -2):

while noone knows what `PyStringNode` really is, your method require object of `PyStringNode` class here. So you basically need to create it like:

```
$string = new PyStringNode();
```

and pass this to your `iSendARequestToWithData()` function, or change function signature and remove `PyStringNode` from it as you do not really seem to benefit from so strict signature.

```
public function iSendARequestToWithData($method, $uri, $string)
```